# How to show the quizzes that the employee did not participate in them?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, IsSent, Description
UserQuiz Table: UserQuizID, QuizID, Score, Username
```

(IsSent is a flag (of a bit type) that indicates if the quiz has been sent to all employees or not)

I need now to write a query that shows the title and description of the quizzes that have been sent to the employee but he did not participate in them. So when the employee goes to his profile in the system, he will see the quizzes that he did participate in them (if any). **How to do that?**

I wrote a general query that shows the quizzes that all employees did not participate in them. It should be specific for a given/specified employee. **So how to modify it?**

**Query:**

```
SELECT     Title, Description
FROM         dbo.Quiz
WHERE     (NOT EXISTS
                          (SELECT     QuizID
                            FROM          dbo.UserQuiz
                            WHERE      (dbo.Quiz.QuizID = QuizID)))
```

Comment: Add a filter on `Username` to the sub query under your `not exists` as you are looking for quizzes where there does not exist a quiz record for that employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:-

```
SELECT Q.Title, Q.Description 
FROM Quiz Q
WHERE     
    (NOT EXISTS                           
        (SELECT UQ.QuizID 
         FROM UserQuiz UQ, Employee E
         WHERE Q.QuizID = UQ.QuizID and E.Username = UQ.Username)
     )
```

Comment: `dbo.Employee` is not a table used in your query so that will error.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Now query should be fine.